# Error in WS-Secured header validation(WSS4j) with UsernameToken TimeStamp for different time zone

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

I have built a web service(top down based) in Apache CXF (2.7.11) with WSS4J with UsernameToken Timestamp feature. When I test the same with SOAP UI the server & client code seems to work fine.

But there is a client code who sends the data in IST (Indian Standard Time) timezone in WS Security header; for that, client receives the error `The message has expired (WSSecurityEngine: Invalid timestamp The security semantics of the message have expired)` is being thrown. Investigating I found the timezone used by WSS4J is UTC. Making the timestampStrict false in WSS4JInterceptor also did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<jaxws:inInterceptors>                  
     <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
     <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
        <property name="properties">
              <map>
                     <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" />
                     <entry key="timestampStrict" value="false"/>
                     <entry key="user" value="test_user" />
                     <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                     <entry>
                            <key>
                                   <value>passwordCallbackRef</value>
                            </key>
                            <ref bean="passwordCallback" />
                     </entry>
              </map>
        </property>
     </bean>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid to send a Timestamp in any time other than UTC time as per the SOAP Message Security profile: "All references MUST be in UTC time.".

Colm.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. However the client code is a legacy one & they are sending the data using IST time zone as they are not sending the data in UTC. Is there any other configuration that can be done in server side, as being a legacy code they don't want to change the client code.

Comment: Your only option is to plug in a custom TimestampValidator implementation. Here is the default TimestampValidator:http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/webservices/wss4j/trunk/ws-security-dom/src/main/java/org/apache/wss4j/dom/validate/TimestampValidator.java?view=markup - You can add a TimestampValidator to the WSS4JInInterceptor via a "wss4j.validator.map" property.

Comment: @ColmOhEigeartaigh, do you have sample code on this: "You can add a TimestampValidator to the WSS4JInInterceptor via a "wss4j.validator.map" property." ?